# Javascript Adding a Class to a <i> inside of an element

Tags: javascript

I have a shameful problem trying to do things without jquery, I'm trying to add a class to an `<i>` element into a `<span>`, I know this is easy to do with jquery,  but I'm failed with Vanilla Javascript:

```
<span id='my1'>
<i>...</i>
</span>

<span id='my2'>
<i>...</i>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i1 = document.querySelectorAll('#my1 i');
    i1.className = 'test'
    i1.textContent = 'yep'


    var i2 = document.getElementById('my2').getElementsByTagName('i')
    i2.className = 'test'
    i2.textContent = 'yap'
    i2..innerHTML = 'what?'
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exmcw2uh/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`.getElementsByTagName('i')` returns a collection, so you have to reference the index you want to modify:

```
var i2 = document.getElementById('my2').getElementsByTagName('i')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `.` here: `i2..innerHTHML`.  Beyond that, `getElementsByTagName` returns an array, which makes sense.  Your array has one member, so you could for example do:

```
i2[0].className = 'test'
i2[0].textContent = 'yap'
i2[0].innerHTML = 'what?'
```

[Here's your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nku5oe5v/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to resolve:

```
var i1 = document.querySelector('#my1 i'); //You want to return a single element, not all matches
i1.className = 'test';
i1.textContent = 'yep';


var i2 = document.getElementById('my2');
var i3 = i2.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]; //Added another var for readability, but you need to specify the first element of the returned array
i3.className = 'test'
i3.textContent = 'yap'
i3.innerHTML = 'what?'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/exmcw2uh/2/